# View only populated when "administer content" is granted

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

So I created a content type "seminar" in Drupal with a bunch of CCK-fields. I then built a view for these seminars with no access restrictions. The view works fine for authenticated users.
As the anonymous user with the permissions to "view content" and all CCK-fields for seminars I can access the page, but I cannot see any seminar-entries. The moment I grant anonymous the permission "administer content", the view gets populated with all the seminars one could wish for.
I guess I've just missed some stupid checkbox somewhere, but I can't for the life of me figure out, what and where it might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to rebuild permissions and clear the Views cache (Views -> Tools). If you did not set any access restrictions in the view, "access content" and the CCK field permissions should be enough.

Administer content is a very dangerous permission, it overrides most of the other content related permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The permission to see nodes is `access permission`, not `view content`, which is not a permission defined from Drupal core modules, nor Views.
Permission to administer should not be given to anonymous users, because those are administrative permissions that should be given to trusted users.

It's probably that the issue is caused from some cache that needs to be clean; try that, and try changing the permissions and saving them.